# Data gets disappeared from reader object c#/MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm noticing a strange behavior while working with mysql data reader in c#.
When i execute query,i get the data and the same i can see in my reader object.
However during debugging when i stops here for a second or millisecond data gets disappeared from reader and it says "Enumeration yielded no results".
Below is my code for the same.
I'm unable to find the solution for the same.

```
 public async Task<bool> SelectAsync(MySqlCommand command)
        {
            DbDataReader reader;
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = command;
                command.Connection = _connection;
                reader = await  cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // extracting fields from reader object code goes here
                }
                reader.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //error log
                _errorMessage = $"{ex}";
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the state of an object at the debug mode or WATCH; that will be filled by a DB call, you must first materialize that.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand any reader collection that enumerates data from datareader during debugging then the `Read` method is automatically called on datareader object  and the reader is advanced to next record or end. Therefore, you see no records if it gets positioned at end. Note that datareader becomes empty once you reach the end position of reader object.

I would recommend you not to show any reader results collection during debugging to overcome this issue.